# How does the matchmaking system work

Tags: hearthstone

I have been playing Hearthstone since the beta invites last year, and have ever since, been wondering, how you are matched in the ranked play-mode.
(note that I don't look for an answer on how it worked in the beta)

When I play ranked games in Hearthstone, I can see that I get matched against players with similar ranks - most of the time. Sometimes I get matched against players with a lower rank or higher rank.

**How does Hearthstone match players against each other in ranked play-mode?**